# angularjs checkbox retaining it's value

Tags: angularjs

I have a modal which comes up with a form, in there is a section which appears when a button is clicked.

In the hidden section I have the following 2 radio buttons:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.CreateChild" name="inventoryType" value="false" />Parent
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.CreateChild" name="inventoryType" value="true" />Child
</label>
```

When a radiobutton is selected i'm able to see the vm.CreateChild values are set, where i'm having an issue is when the modal is closed I set the vm.CreateChild to "",

```
vm.CreateChild = "";
```

However, when the modal appears and I click that button, the last selected radio button is still selected.  i'm not sure why it does that, as the value when I debug is '', is there another way to do this? i would like to clear it at a certain point.

**UPDATE:**
I checked, it was a css framework issue, the framework was wrapping a `<span class='checked'>` around the radio buttons when they were checked.  So angular was working fine with unselecting the buttons, but that span was making it look like it was always checked.

Comment: Have you tried with `ng-value` instead?

Comment: how do you hide/show this section ?

Comment: Have you tried $scope.vm.CreateChild = '';. Do you need to $scope.$apply() it?

Comment: Please see my update, it was not related to Angular

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
vm.CreateChild = angular.copy({});
```

Sometimes I have faced issue with deep copying or setting a value.